# Detecting most frequently recurring symbol from ASCII-characters on C

Tags: c, for-loop

How do I write an implementation for a function that takes as input a sequence of ASCII-characters, and gives the most frequently recurring symbol? I need make it on C, Where my bad?

```
  char mostFrequentCharacter(char* str, int size);



 char value;
 int valueCount = 0;
 for (int i =0; i < strlen(str); i++)
 {
       char oneChar = str[i];
       var totalCount = source.Split(oneChar).Length - 1;;
      if (totalCount >= valueCount)
      {
       valueCount = totalCount;
       value = oneChar;
      }
 }
  return value;
```

The function to be optimized to run on a device with a dual-core ARM-based processors and infinite amount of memory.

Comment: `var totalCount = str(c => c == oneChar);` is the bad. You need to implement this line in C (or to review your algorithm).

Comment: @Inspired, can you help me how it will be in C?

Comment: I believe you are capable of writing a piece of code that counts recurrence of a character in a string, since your assignment implies experience in much more complex subjects like an optimization for ARM and dual-core. I also think that rewriting the 'bad' line in C will not produce 'optimized' function (in fact, it would be as suboptimal as it could be).

Comment: Hang on... this is eerily familiar..

Comment: Oh sorry - you're not Pradeep. You're someone who had their question from 8 hrs ago put on hold.  3 hrs ago, you deleted it and immediately posted it again with some sort of 'code' included.  I see that you have successfully conned some sucker into providing your C code.  I hope you have a long and successful career, but I'm not holding  my breath.

Comment: 10k+ users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876106/detecting-most-frequently-recurring-symbol-from-ascii-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the memory is not an issue as you noted, then you shoud create lookup table where you will store number of occurences for each character. Since input is sequence of ASCII characters, size of the structure should be 256. After checking input and initializing lookup table, in the main for loop, increment number of occurences in the corresponding place in the lookup table, check if the number of occurences exceeded the current maximal count, if so, update current maximal count and current most frequent character. In the end, just return most frequent character. Time complexity of this solution is O(N) and space complexity O(1).

```
char mostFrequentCharacter(char* str, int size) {
    char mosfFrequent;
    int counts[256], i, maxCount = 0;

    // in the case of invalid input, return some invalid character
    if(!str || size < 1)
        return '\0';

    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        counts[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        counts[str[i]]++;

        if(counts[str[i]] > maxCount) {
            maxCount = counts[str[i]];
            mostFrequent = str[i];
        }
    }
    return mostFrequent;
}
```

Comment: If this is going to be used on megabyte chunks of data, you're probably better off splitting the second loop into two: `for (i = 0; i < size; i++) counts[(unsigned char)str[i]]++;` and then `for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) { if (counts[i] > maxCount) { maxCount = counts[i]; mostFrequent = i; } }`.  If you're going to be doing the counting on small strings (say less than 256 bytes long), this is OK as is.  Watch that `unsigned char` cast; if `char` is a signed type, you'll be indexing the counts array with negative indexes unless you have the cast in place.  But this is basically a good solution.

Comment: Also, for normal systems with 4-byte integers, 1 KiB of memory for the array is not going to stress the system, let alone a system with an infinite amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm outline:

1. Declare a 256 element array of integers (pick your size), zero it.
2. Loop over the string:
   2a.   Use each char as index into your array and increment element.
   2b.   If incremented element is largest so far record index.

All done in one pass over the string. Storage 256 * size of integer bytes, but you have "infinite memory" and that's minuscule in comparison ;-)